# SharedPreferences.getStringSet() not found?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

There's something that I don't understand with SharedPreference.

In [this document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) it says that the getStringSet() method is supported from API 1. But I found no method like that. I use API 8 for my apps. What's happening here? Is it not supported anymore?

ps : There's no difference with the SharedPreference.Editor. There's no putStringSet() in the editor class.

screenshot : look.. no getStringSet()

[image]

Comment: Show some code that fails to compile?

Comment: Yep, @abp got it right: its 11, not 1.

Comment: Check out [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361627/how-can-write-code-to-make-sharedpreferences-for-array-in-android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361627/how-can-write-code-to-make-sharedpreferences-for-array-in-android) as a way of storing arrays (Collections etc) in SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

public abstract Set getStringSet (String key, Set defValues) **Since: API Level 11**

In the typeface they use I often mistake the 11 for a 1, too.

Comment: Perhaps you shouldn't use the preferences to store them.

Comment: @dmon: if not preferences for something this trivial, then what?

Comment: For my case it was sufficient to serialize/deserialize an array to/from a string using `TextUtils.join(delimiter, array)` and `TextUtils.split(string, delimiter)`