# Put and get String array from shared preferences

Tags: android, arrays, string, sharedpreferences

I need to save on shared preferences some array of Strings and after that to get them.
I tried this :

`prefsEditor.putString(PLAYLISTS, playlists.toString());` where playlists is a `String[]`

and to get :

`playlist= myPrefs.getString(PLAYLISTS, "playlists");` where playlist is a `String` but it is not working.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

You can create your own String representation of the array like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < playlists.length; i++) {
    sb.append(playlists[i]).append(",");
}
prefsEditor.putString(PLAYLISTS, sb.toString());
```

Then when you get the String from SharedPreferences simply parse it like this:

```
String[] playlists = playlist.split(",");
```

This should do the job.

Comment: Then how do you do getString()?  What do you use as the second parameter in that?

Comment: @IgorG., It's pretty much up to you, implement your own logic of checking the number of items in that string.

Comment: the problem of this is that strings can't contains the character used to separate them from each other. An encoding is required before using this method.

Comment: @Mario Lenci, I use ";;delimiter;;" as separate string

Comment: @dimetil this looks ugly. And still if somebody type ";;delimiter;;" you have a problem. (not mentioning about the fact that you waste memory, and CPU to parse this thing)

Comment: So what is your solution bluesm?

Comment: the saving part could be simplified to:
prefsEditor.putString(PLAYLISTS, TextUtils.join(",", playlists));

Answer (score 39):

From API level 11 you can use the putStringSet and getStringSet to store/retrieve string sets:

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putStringSet(SOME_KEY, someStringSet);
editor.commit();

SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> someStringSet = pref.getStringSet(SOME_KEY);
```

Comment: i thinks it is easier than accepted answer if anyone building app from API level 11 or higher.

Comment: The problem is that Set is not ordered. In contrast to String[]

Comment: I have a string array with values as 
<item>a,0</item>
<item>b,1</item>
now on the click in settings, I want to changes these values. How to use putStringSet in this.

Comment: @pa1pal, you should probably create a new question and explain there exactly what you want to do and what you did up until now

Answer (score 9):

You can use JSON to serialize your array as a string and store it in the preferences. See my answer and sample code for a similar question here:

[How can write code to make sharedpreferences for array in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361627/how-can-write-code-to-make-sharedpreferences-for-array-in-android/7361989#7361989)

Answer (score 4):

```
HashSet<String> mSet = new HashSet<>();
                mSet.add("data1");
                mSet.add("data2");
saveStringSet(context, mSet);
```

where

```
public static void saveStringSet(Context context, HashSet<String> mSet) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    editor.putStringSet(PREF_STRING_SET_KEY, mSet);
    editor.apply();
}
```

and

```
public static Set<String> getSavedStringSets(Context context) {
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
    return sp.getStringSet(PREF_STRING_SET_KEY, null);
}

private static final String PREF_STRING_SET_KEY = "string_set_key";
```

Comment: As noted by @Tomáš Hubálek, `Set` is not ordered and so could change the behavior of your program.

Answer (score 0):

Store array list in prefrence using this easy function, if you want more info [Click here](https://codingmitra.com/shared-prefrence/)

```
 public static void storeSerializeArraylist(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key, ArrayList tempAppArraylist){
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    try {
        editor.putString(key, ObjectSerializer.serialize(tempAppArraylist));
        editor.apply();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And how to get stored array list from prefrence

```
public static ArrayList getSerializeArraylist(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key){
    ArrayList tempArrayList = new ArrayList();
    try {
        tempArrayList = (ArrayList) ObjectSerializer.deserialize(sharedPreferences.getString(key, ObjectSerializer.serialize(new ArrayList())));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return tempArrayList;
}
```

Comment: This link is broken. ObjectSerializer is not a class in Android.