# change of value in string-array android by shared preferences

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-preferences, android-spinner, user-preferences

I want to change the values in an array in shared preferences.
Can we make a string-array in shared preferences and use it in our code.?
How is it possible as I am entering different values and want user to change values as per user need. I want to use those values in spinner.

Comment: you can add multiple value in shared preference on the based of deliminator you can use any special char after insert a value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. Refer to Egor's comment in the link here [Put and get String array from shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965290/put-and-get-string-array-from-shared-preferences)

That is pretty much what you need.

Answer (score 0):

you can not add array in sharedPrefence.. you can only use data type define in [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) doc.
if you put a large number of data in sharedPrefence than  that memory required never be free. so you can use Application class .. the memory of application class will be a free when app is force stop..

Answer (score 0):

insert your values like

```
registrationPreferencesEditor.putInt("arraylength", a.length);
            for(int i=0;i<a.length;i++)
            {
                registrationPreferencesEditor.putInt("a"+(i+1), a[i]);
            }
            registrationPreferencesEditor.commit();
```

retreive your values

```
int lengthOfArray = registrationPreferences.getInt("arraylength", 0);
            int b[] = new int[lengthOfArray];
            for(int i=0;i<lengthOfArray;i++)
            {
                b[i] = registrationPreferences.getInt("a"+(i+1), 0);
                Log.e("b"+(i+1),""+b[i]);
            }
```

before that make sure you have

```
SharedPreferences registrationPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor registrationPreferencesEditor;
int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
registrationPreferences  = getSharedPreferences("registrationPreferences",
            MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
      registrationPreferencesEditor= registrationPreferences
            .edit();
```