# Adding elements and saving that elements to array that is created in strings.xml

Tags: android, arrays, serialization

Suppose **Type** is the name of the array which contains  **A,B,C,D** as elements and is created in **strings.xml**.Now in the form user can either select any of the elements or add new elements.Suppose user adds **E,F,G** .Now what i want to achieve is that anyhow the **Type** array have **A,B,C,D,E,F,G** in it. Using sqlite is done.But i want to save it in the **Type** array only and not anywhere else.Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Since anything that you define in res folder acquires a unique id in R.java, which is an array, and size of array cannot be changed at runtime.. So, it is not possible.

Comment: Create what? If you are talking about creating the R.java, android creates this itself according to the elements you defined in your res folder.

Comment: I meant create the array through code and then try and achieve the same thing

Comment: Also, you don't have write access in res folder.. you only have read access through codes.. because anything that you put in res folder increases the apk size..

Comment: Yes if i do through code is it possible i mean create the array in the java file and not in the xml and if yes then how to go about it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can only save data to persistent storage like SQLite data base, shared preferences or a text file, each of which have different strengths and weaknesses and are suited for different situations, so take your pick.

Comment: is it possible to save array in shared preference.. ?

Comment: it can be done although a bit tricky, see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7057845/save-arraylist-to-sharedpreferences

Comment: seen this one as well it says api level 11 and above and my app is supported from version 4 though it actually should be from 8

Comment: Found one way though saving it as string and the creating the array by using split() function

Comment: Here's one method to save an array of strings to shared preferences regardless of api level: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965290/put-and-get-string-array-from-shared-preferences

Comment: yup thats what i thought.But still i have this question if its possible to create an array in a java file and append an element as my question goes and save that change and once again when i access the java file i get those values without using a text file.May be by creating a class or anything like that.