# Retrieving values from a SharedPreferences string set

Tags: android, set, sharedpreferences

While working on my app, I discovered that the only way to save a number of values (like an array) in shared preferences is by using a set. The problem is, that since the whole set thing is new to me, I don't really know how to retrieve values from it, and placing the values in dynamic text views. I would be glad if someone could show me the correct way of retrieving the values.

Comment: You could use JSON and serialize most objects to a string. Then you can store strings instead of sets. Then you can deserialize later to get your object back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can find your answer here :
[Follow the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965290/put-and-get-string-array-from-shared-preferences)

> From API level 11 you can use the putStringSet and getStringSet to
>   store/retrieve string sets:

```
SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putStringSet(SOME_KEY, someStringSet);
editor.commit();

SharedPreferences pref = context.getSharedPreferences(TAG, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Set<String> someStringSet = pref.getStringSet(SOME_KEY);
```

> The set interface has method which are as follows :
>
> add() : Which allow to add an object to the collection..
>    clear() :
>   Remove all object from the collection.
>   size() : Return the size of
>   element of collection.
>    isEmpty() : Return true if the collection has
>   element.
>   iterator() : Return an iterator object which is used to
>   retrieve element from collection.
>   contains() : Returns true if the
>   element is from specified collection.

Example of java set interface.

```
Set s=new TreeSet();
        s.add(10);
        s.add(30);
        s.add(98);
        s.add(80);
        s.add(10); //duplicate value 
        s.add(99);
        Iterator it=s.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
        {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
```

Comment: What do you mean when you say "SOME_KEY"? The location in the set?

Comment: I already know how to get the set itself, but the thing that i don't know is how to get the values that are inside the set.

Comment: I have edited the answer. Hope to be useful. better to read about java Collection. every java programmer need to learn them. good luck

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you so much!