# save and call Stringbuilder from Sharedpreference

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, stringbuilder

I 'm testing with some iteration with the coding below, with help of `Stringbuilder` and want to directly save the outcome to `Sharedpreference`.

```
save2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick (View v){
        int i;
        int n = 10;

        StringBuilder outoutcome = new StringBuilder();
        for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
            outoutcome.append(i + "\n");
        }

        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("data1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
        editor.putString("outcome1", outoutcome.toString());
    }
}
```

*I also tried `editor.putString("outcome1", String.valueOf(outoutcome));` but unfortunately cannot.

for the retrieve of data in another activity, I had tried using coding below :

```
public static final String DEFAULT = "";
final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("data1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
final String out1 =sharedPreferences.getString("outcome1", DEFAULT);
resultout.setText("Saved data is " + out1 );
```

but the coding above not working. Then, I searched and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965290/put-and-get-string-array-from-shared-preferences) , tried the code as below but still not working.

```
 final String[] getout1= out1.split(",");
 resultout.setText("Saved data is " + getout1 );
```

Can anyone help here? Thank you in advanced !

Comment: Are you called editor.commit after putting value?

Comment: Thank you !!!!!!  I really forgotten to call that one. and after called all things work again... arrrhh....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `apply()` or `commit()` to save the changes.

```
editor.apply();
```

or

```
editor.commit();
```

Comment: Ya , just found that forgotten the editor.commit() . Thought other things causes this problem and lost the focus on this. Thanks.