# What is the fastest way to save set of strings in SharedPreferences?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences

I have 2 data sets

```
String[] wordsArray;
Queue<String> wordsQueue;
```

They store the same data, around 500 strings each, 1-3 words per string. I need to save one of them to `SharedPreference`. What is the best (fastest) way to do it?

Now I just use

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(wordsQueue);
edit.putStringSet("Words", mySet);
```

But it works slower than I want.

Comment: try to do bulkier work in background threads.

Comment: i'm new to java and still not familiar with threads. Anyway, I will try to do it in this way thanks for advice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `apply()` instead of `commit()` which will save the preference in a background thread (i.e. asynchronous).

```
Set<String> mySet = new HashSet<String>(wordsQueue);
edit.putStringSet("Words", mySet).apply();
```

For saving the array of `String` in `SharedPreference` you might consider doing something like this stated [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7965356/3145960).

Comment: Thank you! I guess I just need to read official docs more attentively, ha-ha.

Comment: But is there any way to do the same thing without copying original list to HashSet?