# How to retrieve string array from SharedPreferences stored with key

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-arrayadapter, android-spinner

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("file1",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String clr=sp.getString("color","Not Found");
        dropDown();
        Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        btn.setText(clr);
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                colorChange();
            }
        });
    }

    public  void dropDown(){
        Spinner spin=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        List<String> list;
        SharedPreferences sp=getSharedPreferences("file1",Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        // int size=sp.getInt()
        String clr=sp.getString("color","Not Found");
        list=new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(clr));

        ArrayAdapter<String> adp=new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,list);
        adp.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spin.setAdapter(adp);
    }

    public  void colorChange(){
        EditText ed1=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        String clr= ed1.getText().toString().toLowerCase();
        SharedPreferences sp1=getSharedPreferences("file1", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor ed=sp1.edit();
        ed.putString("color",clr);
        ed.apply();
        ed.commit();
    }
}
```

How can I show all my values in shared preferences in spinner?
I'm making an application which takes color name from user and change background according to given color and also store that value in spinner(combo box) and keep that selected value top of that combo box.

Comment: You did not save a list you just saved a String .

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put and get String array from shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965290/put-and-get-string-array-from-shared-preferences)