# HashSet reorders the info, what can I do to not be reorded?

Tags: java, android, sorting, arraylist, hashset

I'm having doubt and a problem I tried to solve with this Note App I found on Google, which is pretty simple, so I (a beginner) went to try few things on it.
Everytime I save few notes, close app, restart app, it reorganizes the notes alphabetically, which I don't want. I know that Set and ArrayList are different in the sense a Set won't repeat elements, but ArrayList will. Also Set can't guarantee the order when called.

The question is: how is a good way to solve this instrinsecally sorting problem?

I've tried to switch what's HashSet to ArrayList, but the method putStringSet requires a Set in its parameters, which ArrayList isn't.

The following code works (doesn't crash or any other problem) but doesn't work as I want.

I have this part code in the MainActivity

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.tanay.thunderbird.deathnote", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
HashSet<String> set = (HashSet<String>) sharedPreferences.getStringSet("notes", null);

// a lot of other things here

    if (set == null) {
                notes.add("Example Note");
            } else {
                notes = new ArrayList<>(set);         // to bring all the already stored data in the set to the notes ArrayList
            }
```

On NoteEditorActivity I have

```
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    noteID = intent.getIntExtra("noteID", -1);

    if (noteID != -1) {
        editText.setText(MainActivity.notes.get(noteID));
    } else {
        MainActivity.notes.add("");                // as initially, the note is empty
        noteID = MainActivity.notes.size() - 1;
        MainActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
//other things here
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                MainActivity.notes.set(noteID, String.valueOf(s));
                MainActivity.arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.tanay.thunderbird.deathnote", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                HashSet<String> set = new HashSet<>(MainActivity.notes);
                sharedPreferences.edit().putStringSet("notes", set).apply();
            }
```

Comment: Try the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965290/put-and-get-string-array-from-shared-preferences

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to keep the order of the notes, `Array` or `List` is truly the better choice than using `Set`.

To store this into `SharedPreferences`, you can refer to [Put and get String array from shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7965290/put-and-get-string-array-from-shared-preferences)

This question has answers explaining the followings:

1. Jsonify the list and parse it back.
2. Concatenate all the Strings with delimiter and split it back.