# Android saving an ArrayList<CustomObject> onPause and onSaveInstanceState

Tags: java, android, arraylist, onresume, onpause

I have an ArrayList filled with some custom POJO's that I'd like to persist when the user switches screen orientation (onSaveInstanceState) and when e.g. the user hits the back button (onPause).

As far as I know, the SharedPreferences can only hold primitive data types and bundles can not hold references to generic ArrayLists.

Any tips on how to tackle this?

Regards,

Marcus

Comment: Hitting back will not only pause, but also destroy your `Activity`. With that in mind, you'll need to write the data to some sort of file if you want it to survive. Were you instead just referring to instances where the user might be interrupted in their use of your app?

Comment: Answer = http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145606/how-android-sharedpreferences-save-store-object + http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361627/how-can-write-code-to-make-sharedpreferences-for-array-in-android/7361989#7361989

Comment: @PiyushKukadiya  Gson is deprecated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1- create a class and put everything you want to store for example `arraylist` of your `POJO` and make that class implement `Serializable` interface.

```
class MyBundle  implements Serializable {

   ArrayList<POJO> mPOJO;


   MyBundle( ArrayList<POJO> pojo){

    mPOJO= pojo;


   }

}
```

2- write it to file:

```
 ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
 FileOutputStream fout = null;
 try{
        FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream("Your file path");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
        oos.writeObject(mb); // mb is an instance of MyBundle
 } catch (Exception ex) {
        e.printStackTrace();
 }finally {
   if(oos  != null){
     oos.close();
   } 
 }
```

and to get back everything:

```
 ObjectInputStream objectinputstream = null;
 try {
        streamIn = new FileInputStream("Your file address");
        objectinputstream = new ObjectInputStream(streamIn);
        MyBundle mb = (MyBundle) objectinputstream.readObject();

   } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }finally {
     if(objectinputstream != null){
        objectinputstream .close();
     } 
   }
```

Comment: Is there really no other way than creating a file to store one simple array list?

Comment: for `onSaveInstanceState` you can use `ParcelableArray` but for `user hits the back button` you must use `file` or `database`.

Comment: I would rather use a database than writing to a file

Comment: I tried the serialize approach. Where should I serialize my array? OnDestroy?

Comment: if you want to handle `onSaveInstanceState` you should do it at `onStop`.

Comment: So if I understand that right: serialize at onSaveInstanceState, de-serialize at onStart?

Comment: Will this cover events such as user press home or navigate to another activity?

Comment: serialize at `onStop` and `de-serialize` at `onCreate`. Yes.

Comment: I'll try it out tomorrow, if it works I'll set this as the answer. Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 1):

i don't know this is correct method or not but i handle this like this this always success while your app lost all cache data itself then also u can get back serializable  object->

for generic ArrayLists always use serializable

just look at once  http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the List to Json using Gson or Jackson.
Store the string in the Shared preference. some thing like below code

```
String listString = gsonSD.toJson(list<object> instance);
SharedPreferences storeDataPref = getContext().getSharedPreferences("list_store_pref", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
Editor storeDataEditor = storeDataPref.edit();
storeDataEditor.putString("liststringdata", listString).apply();
```

Comment: Ill try it out, where can I download it? (a version that isnt deprecated)

Comment: sorry, I am not able to get...where can i download it?