# set.addAll(myArrayList) doesn't add the items of list in the same order

Tags: android, arraylist, sharedpreferences, linkedhashset

Can't figure it out why set.addAll is adding my list with the orders switched. (still my set is declared as LinkedHashSet)

The code is about getting a Set-List from SharedPreferences, convert it into an ArrayList, add one item to list and then add the whole list to Set.

The code looks something like this:

```
 Set<String> set = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
 List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<String>();

 ///

 set = getSharedPrefSet("mySet");
 stringList = new ArrayList<String>(set);
 stringList.add(message);
 set.addAll(stringList);  //this messes up my order
 saveSharedPrefSet("mySet", set);
```

The first two strings add correctly (as I debugged it) but the third switches position with the second one.

Output:

[image]

The getSharedPrefSet function:

```
Set getSharedPrefSet (String key) {
    sharedPrefs = this.getSharedPreferences("myPreferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    return sharedPrefs.getStringSet(key, null);
}
```

---

### **Workaround**

One solution can be found at [How can write code to make sharedpreferences for array in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7361627/how-can-write-code-to-make-sharedpreferences-for-array-in-android/7361989#7361989)

Comment: What does `getSharedPrefSet` return? If it returns a normal `Set`, there lies your problem.

Comment: @Vucko Yes, it's a normal Set, but as I saw the order that returns it's correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can see what your problem is! Even though you're initialising `set` as a `LinkedHashSet` which is supposed to preserve the order of items, look at this line, after that:

```
set = getSharedPrefSet("mySet");
```

Now, I don't see the `getSharedPrefSet` method implementation here, but looking at the screenshot you provided I can see that `set` is now `HashSet`. So the method must have returned the `HashSet` and thus you're losing the order you want because `HashSet` does not preserve it.

From the docs of `LinkedHashSet`:

> Hash table and linked list implementation of the Set interface, with predictable iteration order. This implementation differs from HashSet in that it maintains a doubly-linked list running through all of its entries.

So what you need to do is to actually take a different approach here, because no matter what you initialise your `set` variable with, it's gonna get overwritten by whatever the `getSharedPrefSet` method returns (so initialisation is obsolete anyway). Find another way around it,  `sharedPrefs.getStringSet` apparently returns a normal `HashSet`.

Comment: Thanks for answer, I was looking into it and I don't think you can get anything else than HashSet from SharedPreferences .getStringSet.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so... Well then you'll need to find some workaround cause this is not gonna work :) Consider accepting the answer cause I think we cracked what the issue was.