# How could i save a unique list of values in Android?

Tags: android, thread-safety, data-storage

I have a list of unique values, lets say for example city names (Japan, Paris) and it could be modified by the application later to be (Paris, New York ). 
what i need is a away to save them and then retrive them. How could this be done and how could i insure if its thread/process safe? (`Set` `Serialization`, `JSON` file, Preferences ?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need is a persistant storage of data . 
so use any of these approches:

1. save an array of citynames into shared preferences and modify
   whenvey you need so , no idea whether its thread safe .
2. us internal/external file to save data , here you can make it thread
   safe by java multithreading
3. use sqlite database , thread safe

Comment: 1- You cant put an array in shared preferences, and saving Sets only introduced in resent API (11 i think) which is not supported by most devices. 2- im thinking of doing so, but do i save it in json file or serialize it ? 3- still cant think of it as good idea since its a little bit overhead for one column

Comment: 1 ) no , its since API level 1 , so you should never think so 3) Agree  .

Comment: if you mean getStringSet it's since API 11 (search the page for Since: API Level 11) http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html and look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5843334/sharedpreferences-getstringset-not-found

Answer (score 0):

You could use sqlite tables for this.

This page describes an example of how to do this.
http://www.screaming-penguin.com/node/7742

Comment: i dont think sqlite is the right thing to do, it feels that its unnecessary overhead for only one column.